# ST_Intersection between MultiPolygon tables leads to gaps, missing intersections

Tags: qgis, postgis, intersection, census

I am trying to intersect two MultiPolygon tables, which are in the same UTM projection, and calculate the area of their intersections. I am getting some surprising results when I examine the intersections, which I retain in a new table. Specifically, each table contains either 2000 or 2010 Census block group boundaries. Here, I find the intersections with a `WHERE` clause, calculate the weight associated with the area of that intersection, and put the results into a new table.

```
SELECT c2000.bkgpidfp00 AS fips2000, c2010.geoid10 AS fips2010, 
  ST_Area(ST_Intersection(c2000.geom, c2010.geom)) / ST_Area(c2000.geom) AS weight,
  ST_Intersection(c2010.geom, c2000.geom) AS geom
  INTO xwalk
  FROM census2000_block_groups c2000, census2010_block_groups c2010
 WHERE ST_Intersects(c2000.geom, c2010.geom) AND NOT ST_Touches(c2000.geom, c2010.geom);
```

**Problem is, there are gaps in the final result. Not all of the intersections are present!** See images below.

Here is the intersection--gaps are in white.

[image: Result of intersection; note the gaps!]

Here are the 2000 (blue) and 2010 (red) block group boundaries--**you can see there are other intersections that should have been found!**

[image]

Finally, just to prove that these intersections make sense, I used QGIS to calculate the intersections as well--and it worked! **Below is the correct intersection from QGIS ("Vector" > "Geoprocessing" > "Intersect").

[image]

**Any ideas why my PostGIS `ST_Intersection` example is failing to produce all of the possible intersections?**

In the interest of reproducibility, here's a shell script to download and subset the data from the U.S. Census:

```
wget ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/pvs/tiger2010st/26_Michigan/26/tl_2010_26_bg00.zip
wget ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/pvs/tiger2010st/26_Michigan/26/tl_2010_26_bg10.zip

unzip ~/Downloads/tl_2010_26_bg00.zip
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -where "COUNTYFP00 IN ('099', '125', '163')" -s_srs "EPSG:4269" -t_srs "EPSG:32617" census_block_groups_2000_utm17n.shp tl_2010_26_bg00.shp

unzip ~/Downloads/tl_2010_26_bg10.zip -d $WD
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -where "COUNTYFP10 IN ('099', '125', '163')" -s_srs "EPSG:4269" -t_srs "EPSG:32617" $WD/census_block_groups_2010_utm17n.shp tl_2010_26_bg10.shp
```

To insert into PostGIS:

```
shp2pgsql census_block_groups_2000_utm17n.shp public.census2000_block_groups | psql -h localhost -d detroit
shp2pgsql census_block_groups_2010_utm17n.shp public.census2010_block_groups | psql -h localhost -d detroit
```

Software versions are:

- QGIS: 2.8.1-Wien
- GDAL/OGR: 1.11.2
- GEOS: 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2
- Proj.4: 480
- PostgreSQL: 9.3.6
- PostGIS: 2.1.0

Comment: Odd, it has to be said. Perhaps you could provide your raw data, as it is hard to see anything wrong with your query.

Comment: Sure, I added a short shell script to download and subset the data using GDAL/OGR and `shp2pgsql`.

Comment: Arthur, I'm a bit surprised that the output of this query was loadable in qgis, because ST_Intersects usually gives some GeometryCollections which are unreadable for qgis. I checked with your data and query and this was indeed the case. Also I am missing the fips columns in the data. Are you sure you this is the only query you used?  In the end I had a complete coverage without gaps on my ST_Intersection, so it should be possible.

Comment: Hi @tilt thanks for your feedback. With regards to GeometryCollections in QGIS, there are three `geom` features associated with the layer when I open it in QGIS but two of them grayed out; I choose the one that is not and which is defined as a Polygon feature and it displays just fine (gaps notwithstanding). With regards to the FIPS code, in my original post I changed the field names in the SQL script for readability. I have now changed it back so it matches the attribute table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ST_Intersection gives geometrycollections in cases where the result gives more than one type of geometry (this happens especially when intersecting near-equal geometries), you have to extract the geometries from the collection first.

I always put a `(ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(geoma, geomb))).geom` around the intersection, regardless of the expected output (note the extra brackets around dump).